# Can I view my ssl FQDN? How do I fix the mismatch

Tags: ssl-certificate, fqdn

I have probably set wrong FQDN while creating ssl certificate.

Now, certificate is installed and site display a 'Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead'

I am quite sure it is FQDN as certificate was bought from a company where i have installed ssl successfully in the past.

I get this detail on the site:

-when visiting https: www.mydomain.com:
Web sites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for www.mydomain.com. The certificate is only valid for mydomain.com.

-when visiting https mydomain.com:

mydomain.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.

How can I view ssl FQDN and how to fix the issue.

Comment: You have most likely a different certificate installed for your main domain and subdomain.

Comment: It seems pretty clear what the problem is. `1.` The certificate is only valid for mydomain.com. `2.` The certificate is self-signed.

Comment: There was something wrong with the server configuration. I played with the server configuration file and it fixed it. Not sure if that is correct but when I had three files in apaches ssl configuration: crt, bundle and key it was fine. When I used key and chain(crt and bundle joined into one file) it brought the problems. As I said it might be different cause. Oh...and it does work on both www. and nothing. It was not self signed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `openssl` command to decode and print certificate contents

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in example.com.pem
```

You should be able to find the DNS names listed on the cert in the Subject Alternative Name: sectilon.